# Can't enable caching in WP Super Cache

Tags: wordpress, apache, caching, super

I'm having problem enable caching with WP Super Cache. Currently running Wordpress freshly installed for testing. The only thing I've done is installed WP Super Cache and removed Akismet and Hello Dolly.

The plugin activates, but I can't enable caching in settings. When I reload the settings page it says "Caching Off" again.

For some reason, it also keeps creating copies of wp-cache-config.php in wp-content, and copies of wp-config.php in the webroot. All these copies gets named a random number like 8734852931.php

A message in WP first says it has added

> define( 'WP_CACHE', true );

to wp-config.php, but it didn't. When I add it manually (above require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');) i get another message:

> Warning! WP Super Cache caching was broken but has been fixed! The script advanced-cache.php could not load wp-cache-phase1.php.
>   The file /home/X/public_html/wp-content/advanced-cache.php has been recreated and WPCACHEHOME fixed in your wp-config.php. Reload to hide this message.

Reloading doesn't hide it and WPCACHEHOME is not put into wp-config.php. If I manually add

> define('WPCACHEHOME', '/home/X/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-super-cache/');

to wp-config.php the message goes away, but cache still wont turn on.

Apache error log says nothing of interest, even on debug level.

I've tried to do it all over again with chmod 777 on the entire webroot with the same results, so I don't think it's permissions.
I've also tried different PHP (running 5.6 now) and Wordpress versions.
There are people running exactly the same server setup as me, who has WP Super Cache running on their sites.

Anyone with an idea on what might be the issue here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solved. It was
"disable_functions = rename"
that caused this issue.

Comment: Can you give a little more information?  This is very unclear to me what you are referring to.

Comment: Hi,
I'm super new for workdpress and PHP. I'm running a AWS lightsail multisite Wordpress powered by bitnami. when I checked my php.ini it says `disabled_functions =`. Can you explain how should I change this line?